# Why is UIWebView on iOS 5 not applying width to empty <td> elements

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, iphone-4

I am displaying in a UIWebView some HTML/css that I build on the fly to display a table of data.

Specifically, the problem is that width set on a `<td>`element via css is NOT honored for empty `<td>` cells on iPhone 4s. It IS working on an iPad but NOT on my iPhone 4s or iOS 5 Simulator?

I have tried copying the generated html/css off the console and directly into a file on my desktop where it also works perfectly in desktop safari and firefox.

Any ideas before I go file a bug report.

Here is the code that generates the css:

```
[htmlPage appendString:@"<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale = 1.0\">\n"];
[htmlPage appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
[htmlPage appendFormat:@"body {font-family:\"Courier New\"; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; background-color:%@;}", cs.bgHTML];
[htmlPage appendString:@"table {margin:auto; border-collapse:collapse;}"];
[htmlPage appendFormat:@"th {padding-bottom:4px; color:%@;}", cs.labelHTML];
[htmlPage appendString:@".row-label {width:10px; padding-right:7px;}"];
[htmlPage appendFormat:@"td {padding:3px; border:1px solid %@; font-weight:bold; color:%@; text-align:center; width:45px; height:45px;}", cs.gridHTML, cs.aspectTextHTML];
[htmlPage appendFormat:@".glyphs {font-family:iPhemeris; color:%@; border:none;}", cs.labelHTML];
[htmlPage appendFormat:@"td .glyphs {color:%@;}", cs.aspectGlyphHTML];
[htmlPage appendString:@"</style></head><body>"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved. There is NO iOS bug with respect to the `<td>` tag. The issue was caused by the use of the Viewport meta tag it was skewing the display on the iphone....